# URL decode special characters - äåö

Tags: ios, objective-c, url-encoding

Trying to URL decode a string with special characters in iOS/objective C

The string is "f%F6rv%E5nad"

Tried the method that uses

```
CFURLCreateStringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding()
```

and

```
[stringToConvert stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Both returns null.

I want to return "Förvånad"

Comment: The correctly decoded string returns a malformed UTF-8 sequence. So, the given string "Förvånad" is not encoded correctly. In order to percent encode correctly, any string must be first represented as a UTF-8 sequence of bytes. Then, percent encoding is applied to the octets. See [RFC 3986](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc398)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string is Latin1 encoded

```
NSString *string = @"f%F6rv%E5nad";
NSString *result =  [string stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", result); // förvånad
```

Comment: @trojanfoe Not on my machine, neither in a Swift playground nor in ObjC

Comment: I used [this page](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/) to check the codes.  However characters above 0x7f require two bytes to encode so I don't think they can possibly be UTF-8, so I think you are right.